# Setting up a 3rd monitor to a PC Dual monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, graphics

My boss has a Dell desktop dual monitor 2007FP connected by VGA but both have DVI. He wants to get a third monitor placed on his treadmill to connect all three. I've spoken to Samsung and Dell and they've told me different things and I want to make sure I am getting the right things before I purchase anything.

One told me to purchase a graphics card with 3 DVI ports which I can't seem to purchase anywhere.

Another said a graphics card and a DVI adaptor are necessary.

Does anyone know the simplest way for me to connect these monitors?

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Just get another, cheap, card - but first make sure that the motherboard can take a second card.  Few standard/non-gaming cards support more than 2 monitors - unless you have something pretty dang new.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as simple as just purchasing a card with 3 outputs.

Check what expansion slots are free in the desktop. 2 of the following cards will do the job if you have enough space on the motherboard for both of them.

[http://www.amazon.com/PNY-Profesional-Business-Graphics-VCQ290NVS-PCIEX16-PB/dp/B000XA9BMA/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1372888276&sr=8-1&keywords=quadro+nvs+290](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000XA9BMA)